# Can ggplot2 work with R's canvas backend

Tags: r, canvas, ggplot2

Having installed canvas from here http://www.rforge.net/canvas/files/

I try to plot:

```
> canvas('test.js')
> qplot(rnorm(100), geom='histogram')
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
Error in grid.Call.graphics("L_setviewport", pvp, TRUE) : 
  Non-finite location and/or size for viewport
>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You found a bug! Just fixed it. Be sure to download version 0.3-0.

Best,

Jeff